# Creating a gateway server to pass all clients via VPN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn

This is really broad so tell me if I'm outside the scope of this site.  With that said....

I want to setup an Ubuntu machine on my network which has an OpenVPN client installed configured to send all network traffic.  I then want to use the Ubuntu machine as a gateway for some devices on my LAN so that they too are using the connection provided by the OpenVPN client.

I've been digging through the Ubuntu forums and am coming up blank, mainly because I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for.

Do I need to be using static routes to accomplish this?  Or is there an easy way to setup this type of configuration?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking how to change how outgoing traffic is routed when leaving your network based on the device generating the outgoing traffic.  Say, for example, have your appleTV use a VPN tunnel instead of your regular default gateway.  If that's the case, you're asking about Policy Based Routing.

---

Prerequisites:

- IPRoute2

What you want is made possible by the above package.  This is typically referred to as [policy-based routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing), and in your specific case [source policy routing](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html#LARTC.RPDB.SIMPLE).

You'll need to complete the following:

- Check which routing table numbers are used: `cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables`
- Create a routing table which includes the machine in question
- Add the default route for the specific table
- Flush the route cache

I don't have a Linux terminal handy; but it should be something like this:

`echo ### tableName >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables` ## pick a number not in use

`ip rule add from ip.add.of.box table tableName`

`ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev tun0 table tableName` ##assuming tun0 is your VPN

`ip route flush cache`

Comment: That's exactly what I was getting at, thanks Sean I'll give this a go.